# Adding show more show less button

Tags: javascript, css

In my website to avoid complexity I trying to add show more and less more option using jQuery. but it doesn't work.

Here I trying to show 1st 10 lists.

After click show more, existing list should be shown

```js
//this will execute on page load(to be more specific when document ready event occurs)
if ($('.ty-compact-list').length > 10) {
  $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').hide();
  $('.show-more').show();
}

$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
  //toggle elements with class .ty-compact-list that their index is bigger than 2
  $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').toggle();
  //change text of show more element just for demonstration purposes to this demo
  $(this).text() === 'Show more' ? $(this).text('Show less') : $(this).text('Show more');
});
```

```css
.ty-compact-list {
  float: left;
}

.show-more {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container menuitem wrapper">
  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list soup"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list indo"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list soup"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list devil"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list platter"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list devil"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list starter"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list starter"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list fry"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list d&i"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list fry"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list fry"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>
  <div class="show-more">Show more</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creating a snippet and including jQuery seems to make it work as expected? Maybe you need to wrap your code in `$(function() { .... });`?

Comment: You want `function open() { $('aaa').one('click', close)};function close({ $('aaa').one('click', open)};$('aaa').one('click', open);`.

Comment: I couldn't find where is the problem..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read more/less jQuery accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324740/read-more-less-jquery-accordion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have some problems.

**1-**$('.show-more').css("display", "block");

**2-**$(this).text($(this).text() === 'Show more' ? 'Show less' : 'Show more');

**3-** Remove `display: none;` from css.

```js
if ($('.ty-compact-list').length > 3) {
  $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').hide();
  $('.show-more').css("display", "block");
}

$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
  //toggle elements with class .ty-compact-list that their index is bigger than 2
  $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').toggle();
  //change text of show more element just for demonstration purposes to this demo
  $(this).text($(this).text() === 'Show more' ? 'Show less' : 'Show more');
});
```

```css
.ty-compact-list {
  float: left;
}

.show-more {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2.5px solid #0f2f16;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container menuitem wrapper">
  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list soup"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list indo"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list soup"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list devil"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list platter"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list devil"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list starter"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list starter"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list fry"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list d&i"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list fry"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>

  <div class="filterDiv ty-compact-list fry"><img class="img1" src="images/a1.jpg" style="float: left">
    <h2 class="head2">onion soup</h2>
    <h3 class="head3">$200</h3>
    <p>(Traditional soup prepared with tamarind juice, pepper corn and selected spice)</p>></div>
  <div class="show-more">Show more</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir. thank you.. .filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border:2.5px solid #0f2f16;
}

Comment: Add `min-height: 300px;` to your css part so that all items will be equal. @ArebhySri